# Number of equivalence relations

Tags: combinatorics, equivalence-relations

How many different equivalence relations can be defined on a set of five elements?

Comment: Hint: Group them according to how many equivalence classes they have.

Comment: After you have obtained the answer you may wish to look up Bell numbers on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: In how many ways can you partition a five element set?

Answer (score 2):

We have $5$ people, and want to find the number of ways to break them up into groups (equivalence classes). With a number significantly bigger than $5$, it would be useful to develop some theory (and there is such theory). With $5$, we just count in a systematic way.

(i) One big happy family, everybody equivalent to everybody else. Clearly there is $1$ way to do this.

(ii) One loner, and four friends. The loner can be chosen in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways, giving $5$ ways.

(iii) A group of three friends, and a group of two friends. The group of three can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways, and then the other group is determined.

(iv) Three, one, one. You can handle this.

(v) Two, two, one. This one is tricky, it is easy to get the wrong count. The loner can be chosen in $5$ ways. For each of these ways, the remaining four can be broken up into two teams of two in $3$ ways, for a total of $15$. To see this, suppose the four people are A, B, C, D. Then A can be teamed with any of the $3$ others.

(vi) Two, one, one, one. You can handle this.

(vii) Everybody by herself. Easy.

Add up.

Comment: In (iii), what do you mean the the other group is determined ?

Comment: I have $5$ people, have decided to split them into a group of $3$ and a group of $2$.  Once I have chosen the people who will form the group of $3$, the rest **must** form the group of $2$.  So choosing who will be in the group of $3$ is the same thing as choosing the division (given that we are using a $3$-$2$ split). I could have instead said we can choose the group of $2$ in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, and the splitting is determined. So $10$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $2^n-n$ where $n$ denotes the number of elements. So here, the answer would be $2^5-5= 32-5 = 27$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. 2^n is like you are separating n items into 2 different groups, but here the two groups are not distinct and there are situations where we have 1 group, 2 groups, 3 groups, 4 groups, and 5 groups.